# Setting up rails production module with mysql on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am new to the linux world and I do apologize if this has been asked before, I could not find the answer I need among the answers.

I am running rails 4.2.1 with mysql 5.5.43 with Passenger and Nginx reverse server installed.

I started having problems when I switched to production mode, first it was trying to go to localhost:3000 which is the loopback used for testing. So I started reading online but could not figure out the correct way to set up the config/database.yml to use the correct url for production. I tried and implement several online suggestions but none worked.

If someone could show me the correct way to configure rails to run mysql in development and production include any env variable that I should set. It would be greatly appreciated.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple databases for testing and development, Then you can do something like this.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: DBNAME
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: paswd
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: DBNAME
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: paswd
  host: localhost
  port: 3306

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: DBNAME
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: paswd
  host: localhost
  port: 3306
```

Comment: Will the my Ububtu "localhost" work in production i.e. accessed via an url? I don't recall if I had my database.yml just like that but I started to get an url of localhost:3000 after I created my first record via Chrome. Also I wanted to use a strong pwd. Will I be exposing my database if I write the username/password like that on my yml file?

Comment: It will work on your production server. You do not have other options. You have to write the password in the yml file. Make sue you only give the required permission for the yml file.

Comment: Fawzan, thanks for your help. My installation is broken right now so I have to fix it before I continue with my development.

Comment: Fawzan, thanks for your help. My installation is broken right now so I have to fix it before I continue with my development. Now I know that I can generate a secret key base and add it to my environment also an encrypted password and add it to the environment so that the production part of my yml file has password: <%= ENV[MYDB_PASSWORD %>.  Now I haven't been able to test this yet, but regardless thanks for your input, I'll post some comments here once I'm able to test this.